# NodeJS + Mongodb - Property hidden

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to retrieve an user object from my mongodb database :

```js
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  var user = await User.findOne({ _id: '5fe30ba2d8f18b353ce6c7c2' }).select('+password +token');
  // it's ok, I can display my password
  console.log(user.password);
  // I don't have my password
  console.log(user);
  res.status(200).send(user);
});
```

Here is my model :

```js
const user = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    unique: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    validate: isEmail,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min: 6,
    select: false
  },
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  dateOfBirth: Date,
  description: String,
  city: String,
  phone: {
    type: String,
  },
  social: Social,
  timeToSpend: {
    type: String,
    enum: [
      'USER.TIME_TO_SPEND.VERY_LITTLE',
      'USER.TIME_TO_SPEND.LITTLE',
      'USER.TIME_TO_SPEND.PARTIAL',
      'USER.TIME_TO_SPEND.THREE_QUARTER',
      'USER.TIME_TO_SPEND.FULL'
    ]
  },
  isAvailable: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  isProfitableOnly: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  theme: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  isConnected: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  isEmailConfirmed: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  token: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    select: false
  },
  skills: [
    {
      name: String,
      rating: {
        type: Number,
        min: 1,
        max: 5
      }
    }
  ]
}, {
  timestamps: true,
  versionKey: false
});
```

'token' field is not hidden but 'password' field is just hidden when I retrieve my user object.

I tried to modify my password field on the schema, I tried removing the 'select: false' property but it doesn't work either

I tried to modify my user object like that : `JSON.stringify(user)` but it doesn't work either

Could you help me please?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to recreate a schema without indicating `select: false`?

Comment: Yes, I tried, it doesn't work

Comment: I can't reproduce your case. I took your schema, created one user using `const User = mongoose.model("User", userScheme)` and then used your code with `console.log` - I got a password and and object with `password` field as well

Comment: also if @Anatoly solution doesn't work consider dropping the collection.

Comment: @ELRECO please delete your collection in MongoDB by using mongo CLI or other tool and then run your code again. Hopefully, this will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
const user = await User.findById('5fe30ba2d8f18b353ce6c7c2').select('password token');
res.status(200).send({...user._doc})
```